# Dividing monthly sales forecast by day based on previous daily sales data

Tags: machine-learning, google-bigquery

I have a budget for a year divided by months and I want to divide it by days using daily sales from previous years. Can I do this with machine learning and if so how? I prefer Google BigQuery ML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To forecast daily sales from the previous year, you can use the [ARIMA_PLUS model](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create-time-series) in BigQuery ML to create a model and can use [ML.FORECAST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-forecast) to get the forecasted value.

To divide by days, you can

```
SELECT
  forecast_timestamp,
  forecast_value / (
  CASE
      WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM forecast_timestamp)=1 THEN 31 
      WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM forecast_timestamp)=2 THEN 28
      WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM forecast_timestamp)=3 THEN 31
      WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM forecast_timestamp)=4 THEN 30
      ...
  END)
FROM
  ML.FORECAST(...)
```

Comment: but if I already have a monthly forecast and want to divide it by days?

Comment: I updated the above answer a little bit. Is that what you want?